# How to explicitly unSubscribe from observable after the onComplete

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

In the following code, how and where to put `unSubscribe` to make un-subscription of the `Observable` explicitly exactly after finishing the `onComplete`?.

```
getObservable()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            doSomething();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            thereIsError();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Boolean status) {
            updateView();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save `Disposable` returned by `subscribe` method and use it inside `onCompleted` callback

```
Disposable d = 
getObservable()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            doSomething();
            d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            thereIsError();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Boolean status) {
            updateView();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What if there's an exception and `onError` gets called? WIll that lead to memory leaks because the stream is not disposed?

Answer (score 5):

```
 disposables.add(sampleObservable()
            // Run on a background thread
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            // Be notified on the main thread
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    // Do some work for completion
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                     // Do some work for error
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String value) {
                    // Do some work for next
                }
            }));
```

And clear and unsubscribe

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    disposables.clear(); // do not send event after activity has been destroyed
    disposables.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you have no reason to explicitly unsubscribe as that is done by the observer chain. You can test this yourself by adding this operator:

```
.doOnUnsubscribe( () -> System.out.println("Unsubscribed") )
```

Comment: Any termination event (error or completion) unsubscribes (unless you are using something like `.retry()` )

Answer (score 1):

just use take(1) if you want it to unSubscribe right away.  after you call take(1) it should make onComplete get called.

```
Disposable d = 
getObservable()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .take(1)//take the first, then stop emissions
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            doSomething();
            d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            thereIsError();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Boolean status) {
            updateView();
        }
    });
```